# Is there a difference between how we set the state in React?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

first, sorry if already exists this kind on question.

In order to set a state in a React class, we call `setState()`.

My question is, is there a difference between v1:

```
setState({firstState: value1, secondState: value2})
```

and v2:

```
setState({firstState: value1})
setState({secondState: value2})
```

Can be possible for the v2 to make the application running difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of React [batches state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and *can* [combine separate `setState` calls](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) under certain circumstances.

Just set the state of whatever variable you need to update when you need to update it. The difference in performance between the two is negligible.